# NHibernate - how to query against subclass properties while returning the super class?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Using NHibernate; is it possible to query against a super class while performing restrictions at the subclass level?

For example (appologies for the psuedo-code):

```
Class A
   Property Prop1
End Class

Class B
   Inherits Class A
   Property Prop2
End Class

Class C
   Inherits Class A
   Property Prop3
End Class
```

How would I perform a query as follows:

```
from A where Prop1 = 'foo' AND 
((if A is B) then B.Prop2 = 'bar' OR
 (if A is C) then C.Prop3 = 'bar')
```

Is something like this possible using Nhibernate.Linq? What about hql or the criteria API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since HQL and ICriteria are Domain-query tools i find it hard to expect such a functionality.

AFAIK the only close thing is using ICriteria's Expression.Sql() where you query the superclass but inject subclass specific fragments with pure sql. There, the expression would be like

```
crit.Add(
  Expression.Sql(@"(({alias}.DiscrimCol = :subClassADiscrimVal AND {alias}.Col2 = :barVal) 
    OR ({alias}.DiscrimCol = :subClassBDiscrimVal AND {alias}.Col3 = :barVal))", 
    new object[] { "subA", "subB", "bar" }, 
    new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.String,NHibernateUtil.String,NHibernateUtil.String } )
);
```

not nice but it works

The other way would be using an `ISQLQuery` which at least allows the SELECT part to be domain specific (and using `.AddEntity()`) so you can still select your managed superclass and the WHERE part contains subclass specific fragments

========= UPDATE ==========

On a second thought, there is a way to implement this via HQL or ICriteria but it more of a workaround and is less performant because it involves subqueries. example in ICriteria:

```
    nhSes.CreateCriteria(typeof(Super))
        .Add(
            Restrictions.Disjunction()
                .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(ChildA))
                                                    .SetProjection(Projections.Id())
                                                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ChildAProp", barVal))))
                .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(ChildB))
                                                    .SetProjection(Projections.Id())
                                                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ChildBProp", barVal))))
        )
```

i am quering each child, project its id and then select the super class, limiting the ids with IN from the projected child ids.

Comment: Thanks for this; unfortunate that there isn't a cleaner approach other than using native sql. I wonder if performing a union operation would be a better option?